# Variable Protection Level in Script

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am creating a script programatically. However I cannot access the dataset from the modeule. See "Sample" below. ('ds' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.)

In the Sub main() I can access ds without a problem
In the Sub test() in Cacl_Module I cannot access ds.

```
Namespace Evaluator

Public Class Evaluator
    Public ds As New DataSet
    Public ComboBox1 As New ComboBox
    Public CheckBox1 As New CheckBox
    Public TextBox1 As New TextBox

    Sub main()
        Debug.Print(ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Count)
        Debug.Print(CheckBox1.Checked)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Module Calc_module
    Sub test()
        Debug.Print(ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Count)
        Debug.Print(CheckBox1.Checked)
    End Sub
End Module

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `ds` is a member of the `Evaluator` class. In the `Main` method of the `Evaluator` class, you can access its members. But in the `test` method of the `Calc_Module`, you don't have an instance of `Evaluator`. You should create one, like that:

```
Public Module Calc_module
    Sub test()
        Dim MyEvaluator as new Evaluator()
        Debug.Print(MyEvaluator.ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Count)
        Debug.Print(MyEvaluator.CheckBox1.Checked)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Or even better (no need to duplicate code)

```
Public Module Calc_module
    Sub test()
        Dim MyEvaluator as new Evaluator()
        MyEvaluator.main()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Yup that worked. I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks for pointing it out to me.